# What could be causing a Macbook Pro crontab script to fail moving files with 'No such file or directory' error when manually running the script works?

Tags: bash, macos

I have a macbook pro for work, and I am trying to set up a very simple script that essentially should be moving all files from one directory to another. It fails to do so. I've tried reviewing a few similar issues, but nothing I've tried so far works.

```
mv: rename /Users/cbell/Downloads/Temp_Case_Files/* to /Users/cbell/Temp/*: No such file or directory
mv: rename /Users/cbell/Downloads/Temp_Logs/* to /Users/cbell/Temp/*: No such file or directory
mv: rename /Users/cbell/Downloads/Temp_School_Files/* to /Users/cbell/Temp/*: No such file or directory
```

The script I'm running is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/mv /Users/cbell/Downloads/Temp_Case_Files/* /Users/cbell/Temp
/bin/mv /Users/cbell/Downloads/Temp_Logs/* /Users/cbell/Temp
/bin/mv /Users/cbell/Downloads/Temp_School_Files/* /Users/cbell/Temp
```

Comment: this should be on [unix.se], [su] or [apple.se]

Comment: What does your script do when you call it from the command line instead of from a cron job? If it's the same result either way then remove all the cron references from your question as it's irrelevant and just cluttering up and complicating your question.

Comment: So when I run the script manually without cron, it works as long as there are files in all the directories.

Comment: You would be correct though that it was a scripting issue and not a cron issue as I thought.

Comment: As you can see from the error message in the crontab output, there is a literal (unexpanded) asterisk in the source and the destination. Also you see that the crontab script uses `rename` and not `mv`, so don't compare apple with pears. For debugging the crontab script, put a `shopt -s failglob; set -x` as the first statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that it fails like this when the directories are empty. In that case, the glob (`*`) doesn't match anything, so the shell doesn't expand it, and `mv` tries to move a file named "*", which doesn't exist.

To demonstrate (not on Mac, so details may differ):

```
~$ mkdir /tmp/empty
~$ mv /tmp/empty/* /tmp
mv: cannot stat '/tmp/empty/*': No such file or directory
~$
```

To confirm my suspicion: Does your script work if you run it twice in a row?

Comment: probably. Also * doesn't match files starting with "." so that's something to watch out for.  I kinda think this is a flaw in the way Unix handles things, there's no really clean way to do this, other than doing a shell loop, which is a bit annoying for such a simple requirement.

Comment: You would be correct. Looks like I just need to be adding in a conditional to the script to check that there are files for each directory before running the mv command.

Comment: There was also a hidden file in 2 of those directories that was causing some issues, so I also was able to get rid of those. I'll watch for the scheduled task to be ran and verify everything is working properly now. Thanks for the recommendations!